# Bootstrap Tab Panels with a Jinja2 for loop

Tags: jinja2, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get bootstrap 4 dev tabs working with a for loop in jinja2.

Here's the test code I'm trying:

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    {% for e in range(1,3) %}
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link {% if loop.index == 1 %}active{% endif %}" href="#{{ e }}" role="tab"
           data-toggle="tab">{{ e }}</a>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    {% for e in range(1,3) %}
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade {% if loop.index == 1 %}in active{% endif %}"
           id="{{ e }}">{{ e }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

The nav tabs function as expected, two tabs are visible, "1" and "2", and the active class is correctly applied.

However the content tabs do not change when clicking between nav tabs. The content tab is static on "1".

Changing the loop.index condition to loop.index == 2 means the tab content is static on "2".

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
{% for club in clubs %}
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link {% if loop.index == 1 %}active{% endif %}" href="#{{ club }}" role="tab"
       data-toggle="tab">{{ club }}</a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

```
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
{% for club in clubs %}
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade {% if loop.index == 1 %}in active{% endif %}"
       id="{{ clubs }}">{{ clubs }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Changing the for loop from a range to the actual NDB datastore query worked.